# How to create a proper sum function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a sum function. When I run it through two different arrays (with same values), it's giving me different results. I can't really tell where I did wrong. It seems when I'm generating the array using the 'range' function, it's looping twice.

```js
var myArr = [];
var tempArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function range(start, end) {
  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    myArr.push(start);
    start = start + 1;
  }
  return myArr;

}

function sum(arr) {
  var sumArr = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sumArr = sumArr + arr[i];
    //console.log(sumArr);
  }
  return sumArr;
}


console.log(range(1, 10)); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
console.log(tempArr); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] 


console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); //110
console.log(sum(tempArr)); //55
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `range(1, 10)` returns `Array[20]`. You must declare `var myArr = [];` in `range` function.

Comment: there are more concise alternatives for `range()` and `sum()` functions

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `var myArr = [];` was a global variable. So pushed elements in the first console attempt will be there until they are cleared. You can use local variable in the function instead.

```js
var tempArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function range(start, end) {
  var myArr = [];
  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    myArr.push(start);
    start = start + 1;
  }
  return myArr;
}

function sum(arr) {
  var sumArr = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sumArr = sumArr + arr[i];
    //console.log(sumArr);
  }
  return sumArr;
}


console.log(range(1, 10)); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
console.log(tempArr); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] 


console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); //55
console.log(sum(tempArr)); //55
```

Comment: Order *matters* when you test things.  If you don't understand why something isn't returning what it should, you should eliminate all but the essential to test it.  In this case, you (@fokusfocus) would have seen a difference.

Comment: @Rejith: Ok I understand now. Sorry, a bit new to all this, but your explanation clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) :

You can use `._sum` function.

```
var tempArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sum  = _.sum(tempArr)
```

Don't forget to add the library if you want to use it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kq9gtdr0/17/)